# What describes parents who do not scold their children?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is a suitable word that describes parents who don't scold or punish their child for juvenile delinquency?
 Is "doting parents" a correct description?

Comment: *Juvenile delinquencies* sounds awfully peculiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Permissive](http://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Permissive%20Parenting)*** is a term often associated with parents who are too "indulgent" with their children:

> - ***Permissive parenting (also known as indulgent parenting)*** is a parenting style that is characterized by having few and inconsistent rules and a relaxed attitude to parenting that is more like a friend than a parent.
> - This was one of the three original parenting styles developed by Diana Baumrind. Permissive parents exhibit very loving and nurturing behavior towards their children and frequently use bribery in order to get them to behave. There are not many demands or governing rules within a permissive parented household.

(www.alleydog.com)

Comment: This is a highly complex area of debate. But sticking to the language issue, the term *permissive* is usually employed in a disapproving sense, and *indulgent* even more so. Some people might call it *democratic* parenting, or *warm*, *loving* or *supportive* parenting. .

Comment: What @WS2 said. Likewise, *lax*.